# Android - show more button in list row if row is more than two lines

Tags: android-listview, expandablelistview

I have a custom list view. Requirement is that if any row have texts which are more than two lines then show only two lines and show more button above to text and when user click on more button, it's should show all the rows content whatever the in 3 or 4 lines there. I search for various blogs but could not get the solution. can any one help me on it?
For getting lines of texts using following code:

```
                ViewTreeObserver vto = msg.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                       Layout l = msg.getLayout();
                       if ( l != null){
                          int lines = l.getLineCount();
                          if ( lines > 0)
                              if ( l.getEllipsisCount(lines-1) > 0){
                                  txtMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                        msg.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                              }
                       }  
                    }
                });
```

but issue is that more button is not showing when list more than visible area.

Answer (score 0):

Using onGlobalLayoutListner, it was not getting called for invisible list items.
when used the following code, it's worked.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = msg.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {                          
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Layout l = msg.getLayout();
                       if ( l != null){
                          int lines = l.getLineCount();
                          if ( lines > 0)
                              if ( l.getEllipsisCount(lines-1) > 0){
                                  txtMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                        msg.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                              }
                       } 
            return true;
        }
    });
```